# mysql variables declaration with queries in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and would want have this code that works perfectly in mysql but refuses to work in my php code. Below is the said mysql query...

```
set @maxDate = (select MAX(login) from logs where userId=3 );
set @currentDateTime = now();                                            set @diff = timestampdiff(minute, @maxDate, @currentDateTime);                     set @duraMin = @diff DIV 60;
set @duraSec = @diff MOD 60;                                                    set @duration = concat(@duraMin,'min',' ',@duraSec,'sec');                      

UPDATE logs SET logout= @currentDateTime, duration=@duration  WHERE userId = 3 AND login=@maxDate;
```

I would be really grateful if i could be helped here. Thanks

**EDIT**
    The idea behind the above code is that, there is a table called Logs in my database with columns userID, login, logout and duration. Every time a user login, i insert into Logs table, userID and login date time with the rest of the fields null(logout and duration). 
    When he logout, an update is done on the table where the most recent login "MAX(Login) WHERE userID = 'current_user_Id'" with the corresponding userID and the logout date time is inserted with the corresponding duration calculated and also inserted. 
    Please i would be grateful any help or even a better idea.thanks

Comment: Where's the PHP usage?

Comment: Thanx for your concern. I've been able to find my way through with updating the logout column with the corresponding login, but what am left with is to set automatically update that same row's duration column that is, login and logout difference. Thanx again

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in stored procedure and call this inside PHP. It help you to run this query easily and faster

Comment: thank but i don't have much idea about stored procedures in php....would but grateful if you could help me out

Answer (score 0):

From PHP you first have to [connect to MySql.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Then you can use the connection to [query the selected database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

The query that PHP sends to MySQL is a string. If the query is successful it will, say in case of ac `select` query,  return a [row count](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp) `>=0`.

In your case, an update query; 
count returned:

`-1` -> error in query

`0` -> nothing to update/no changes found

`>0` -> rows affected

PHP will not give you a reason why your query failed. It just passes the string and gives you the feedback from MYSQL.